# Unit test of Spring boot service with private fields and @PostConstruct

Tags: java, unit-testing, spring-boot

I have a Spring boot service defined like this

```
@Service
public class MyService {
    private String field1;
    private String field2;

    @Autowired
    private AnotherService anotherService

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        anotherService.initField1(field1);
        anotherService.initField2(field2);
    }

    public String foo() {
        return field1 + field2;
    }
}
```

How should I write a unit test for `foo`.  Well, it's more about how to deal with class fields and the `PostConstruct` methods.

Thanks!!

EDIT:
  Added `AnotherService` as a field as well.

Comment: Why do you think you need a PostConstruct? Why can't you use a normal constructor?

Comment: It's a service.  Why do I need a constructor?  So, even I use constructor, how do I write the unit test?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following example shows a `@Service` Bean that uses constructor injection to obtain a required `AnotherService` bean:

```java
@Service
public class MyService {
    private String field1;
    private String field2;

    private final AnotherService anotherService;

    public MyService(AnotherService anotherService) {
        this.anotherService = anotherService;
        this.anotherService.initField1(field1);
        this.anotherService.initField2(field2);
    }

    public String foo() {
        return field1 + field2;
    }
}
```

Note you can omit the `@Autowired` becuase `MyService` has one constructor. See [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#using-boot-spring-beans-and-dependency-injection) for more info.

**testing with Spring**
Use the [@RunWith](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/runner/RunWith.html)([SpringRunner.class](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/context/junit4/SpringRunner.html)) and [@SpringBootTest](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/context/SpringBootTest.html) to inject `MyService` and start using it:

```java
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class MyServiceTest {
    @Autowired    
    private MyService service;

    @Test
    public void testFoo() {
        String expResult = "";
        String result = service.foo();
        assertEquals(expResult, result);
    }
}
```

**testing without Spring**

```java
public class MyServiceTest2 {
    private MyService service;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        service = new MyService(new AnotherService.Fake());
    }

    @Test
    public void testFoo() {
        String expResult = "";
        String result = service.foo();
        assertEquals(expResult, result);
    }
}
```

Here `Fake` is a fake implementation of the `AnotherService` interface which allows you to have a pure unit test.

Comment: This is not using `SpringRunner`, then what if I have a dependency on another service?  Let me add more to the question.

Comment: This is about unit testing. `@SpringBootTest` is about starting a container for integration testing. That of course doesn't mean it won't work,

Comment: @DoeJohnson you are right, added a new example of a pure unit test.

Answer (score 1):

Writing good, testable code can be hard. There are some pitfalls waiting for everyone to fall into sooner or later.

As a rule of thumb, try to avoid field level injection, use constructor parameter injection instead:

```
@Service
public class MyService {

    private AnotherService anotherService;

    @Autowired
    MyService (AnotherService anotherService) {
         this.anotherService = anotherService;
    }

}
```

This is the cleanest solution. You can call the constructor from your tests, spring will inject dependencies the same way at runtime. So there is no difference to deal with.

The same goes for any life cycle constructs like `@PostConstruct`. If you can avoid them, do it. Let the constructor handle it. If you absolutely have to keep them around, well, the only logical solution is to manually call them from your test code.

Now, how to setup services that at runtime would be autowired by the container?

For unit testing, you basically have three options (in no particular order):

1. If the required service is rather simple and can easily be constructed, create and pass it as the framework would do.
2. If the service has a limited interface that does not change too often, create a fake service.
3. Use a mocking lib like mockito (spring-boot-test provides it by default).